# All possible combinations in adding elements of list c#

Tags: c#, list

```
namespace CombinationWork
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> List = new List<int>(new int[] {1,2,5,10});
            for (int noSelected=0;noSelected<4;noSelected++)
            {
                for(int noAdded=0;noAdded<4;noAdded++)
                {
                    List.Add(List[noSelected]+List[noAdded]);
                }
            }
            List = List.Distinct().ToList();
            for (int display = 0; display < List.Count; display++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( List[display]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Guys assistance needed.
let say i have an array:
int[] a={1,2,5,10};
I want to add all the elements with each other .Example:

- 1
- 2
- 2+1=3
- 5+1=6
- 5+2=7
- 5+2+1=8
- 10
- 10+1=11
- 10+2=12
- 10+2+1=13
- 10+5=15
- 10+5+1=16
- 10+5+2=17
- 10+5+2+1=18

I'm getting some inaccurate values. The error lies in using the nested for loops but i dont know what else to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For n numbers, it should give you 2 pow n combinations.  Use binary representation of numbers to publish all combinations.

Example,
    Binary - 001 decimal - 1
    Binary - 010 decimal - 2
    Binary - 011 decimal - 3
    ...
    Binary - 001 decimal - 1

From above truth table, include a number to summation only when respective binary digit is 1

Example, your numbers in list [1, 2, 3]; interpret as follows, 
    For Binary - 001, you should get 3
    For Binary - 010, you should get 2
    For Binary - 011, you should get 2 + 3 = 6